# Update datagrid on Add, Remove, Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, wcf, datagrid

Im working on a WPF application, where I have a datagrid that I fill with data from a method that returns a List from my database. I've read that if you want to dynamically update your datagrid at runtime, you have to make a viewmodel and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on every model, and then call the PropertyChanged event on each property of my objects.

However, I was wondering if there was a simpler way of doing this, as I already have all of my models in different layer in my architecture, that are completely independant of my WPF application.

My question is, what can I do to make sure that my datagrid gets updated when I **Add**, **Remove,** or **Update** something in the database directly, without interacting with my WPF but still being able to see those changes while the program is running?

I would appreciate some help here, as I'm no expert but eager to learn.

Below you can see that I fill my datagrid from my list, and call it in my constructor.

```
// userClient.GetAllUsers() returns all users from the database
// Constructor, casting list from DB (Generics.List) to 
// Observablelist so that it can be updated dynamically I guess?
public Default()
{
    userList = new ObservableCollection<UserReference.User>(userClient.GetAllUsers());
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadUserData();
}

// Filling my datagrid from my observablelist 
private void LoadUserData()
{
    try
    {
        userDatagrid.ItemsSource = userList;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data couldnt be loaded", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        throw;
    }
}
```

To illustrate what I want to achieve even further, this remove method (and click event) might give some insight, I have to call the refresh() method on the datagrid items which is what I would like to avoid.

```
private void removeUserButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveUser();
    userDatagrid.Items.Refresh();
}

private void RemoveUser()
{
    UserReference.User user = (UserReference.User)userDatagrid.SelectedItem;
    var selectedRow = userDatagrid.SelectedIndex;
    if (user != null)
    {
        try
        {
            userList.RemoveAt(selectedRow);
            userClient.RemoveUser(user.id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as `userList`is an `ObersveableCollection` you should not need to call `Refresh`. You just need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`if you update your properties in code-behind and want reflect these changes in the UI.

Comment: have you thought about what will happen if the user press `Delete` key?

Comment: Ah okay, I see that, I just removed the Refresh method from the remove button, thank you.

Comment: Haha no I actually havent at all, I didnt even know that you could do that in the datagrid. Another problem, to add to the list

Comment: By the way, If I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, I would still have to make a viewmodel class of one of my models right? To specify which properties I want to update?

Comment: You can implement it on your Model class directly. But I would recommend to take a look at the MVVM pattern. It's really worth it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129517/discussion-between-kingkong-and-mat).